# How reliable is the format of multipart message body?

Tags: http, post, standards, multipartform-data

I've been looking at the standard of message body for multipart post requests. There are statements about how to meet the standard. How fields should be placed, and so on.

How reliable is this standard for data sent from clients? In particular web browsers.

For instance on the php site for file uploads there's this:

> PHP is capable of receiving file uploads from any RFC-1867 compliant
>   browser.

Does that mean the all modern browsers are RFC-1867 compliant?

I'd rather not attempt to test them all. If there is a resource about this I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: well, it's what all browsers use when you click 'submit' on a `<form method="POST" />` and a file field... so: yes, it's reliable :)

Comment: @mb21 That's what I thought. I'm not sure that's an answer though. Also the post method will send a url encoded string if there isn't a type specified. Any way if it's good enough for php I suppose it's good enough for me.